# Copying specific values between structs

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, struct, singly-linked-list

Using C++ and not using STL containers' functions, I am trying to copy values from one struct to another in a specific fashion.

I have such struct (singly-linked list), and this is how I add new elements to it:

```
struct Node {
    Node *next;
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
};

void AddElement(Node *&head, const std::string &name, const std::string &surname)
{
    head = new Node {head, name, surname};
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Node *pointer = nullptr; 
AddElement(pointer, "Alex", "Smith"); 
AddElement(pointer, "Robert", "Johnson"); 
AddElement(pointer, "George", "Smith"); 
AddElement(pointer, "Oscar", "Williams");
```

I also have an another struct:

```
struct Result {
    Result *next;
    std::string surname;
};
```

I want to copy all "surname" values from the first Node list to the new Result list only once per given "surname" value.

That is, if I have in my Node linked list such surnames: `"Smith", "Johnson", "Smith", "Johnson", "Williams"`, I want to have `"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams"` in my Result list.

I'm new to C++, pointers and structs. How do I approach this?

Comment: I'm not using standard libraries. What's `std::string` then?

Comment: Sorry, I meant STL containers' functions.

Comment: does that mean no `std::set`?

Comment: Yup, exactly. Cannot use std::set, std::vector, and such. And theirs' methods.

Comment: Well the 'brute force' way is to iterate through your original list, and on each item ask youself whether you've added that surname before. Detecting whether you've added a surname before mean iterating through your result list. So you'll end up with one loop inside another. It's not pretty but it's the easiest approach.

Comment: Just curious: why can't you use std containers? Exercise purpose? Teacher  requirement? Not enough space in embedded system? ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible algorithm to reduce searching, without changing the basic struct definitions:

Keep your list of Result structs sorted alphabetically. Whenever you check for a surname, search through the Result structs until you either: (1) Find an exact match, and so don't add it (2) Find a surname alphabetically past the one you are searching for. In this case, add the new surname directly before the one you found.

This may not be the best or only solution, but I offer it as a direction to go in.